# EPPlus ignoring fractional seconds?

Tags: c#, datetime, epplus

Using EPPlus to write the contents of a datagrid to an Excel file.  This function:

```
public static void FormatExcelCell(OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRange cellExcel,
                                   object cellValue, 
                                   System.Type cellValueType, 
                                   bool UseAlternateDateFormat = false)
{
    cellExcel.Value = cellValue;
    if (cellValue.ToString() != Constants.ValueForMissingTag)
    {
        if (cellValueType == typeof(System.DateTime))
            cellExcel.Style.Numberformat.Format = 
            UseAlternateDateFormat ?
            Constants.FormatDateTimeAlternateExport : 
            Constants.FormatDateTime;
    }
    else
    {
        cellExcel.Style.Fill.PatternType = 
                                    OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        cellExcel.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor
                                              (Constants.ColorForMissingTag);
    }
}
```

If the format string is set to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ff", then the dates in the Excel file look like this: 2018-06-18 15:45:25.ff

If the format string is set to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.00", then the dates in the Excel file look like this: 2018-06-18 15:45:25.00

Is EPPlus removing the fraction of a second (I know it's there because I can see it in the datagrid), or is it mangling the format string somehow?  Is this a bug?  Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Update: updated EPPlus from 4.1.0.1 to 4.5.2.1 and added OpenXML which wasn't previously needed; still produces wrong datetime formats as above.

Comment: The solution is `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000"`,

Comment: If my solution worked?

Comment: Result: 2018-06-18 15:45:25.000

Comment: It worked for me.  You are sure cellValue contains milliseconds?  The only difference in my code, I set format before assigning the value.

Comment: I can see the milliseconds in the datagrid.  I tried updating the value after the format assignment instead of before, but that didn't make a difference.

Comment: I was looking in the wrong place.  Value passed in cellValue was a DateTime variable resulting from a call to DateTime.TryParse().  It doesn't say so in the docs, but that function cuts off the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I do it in my code.  This is a Extension method.

```
    public static void SetCellDateTimeWithMsValue(this ExcelRange cell, DateTime? value)
    {
        cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000";
        if (!value.HasValue) return;
        cell.Value = value.Value;
    }
```

Comment: I'm crediting you for an answer even though this isn't, because your question "You are sure cellValue contains milliseconds?" eventually led me to find that I had called a function that cut off the milliseconds without realizing it (see above).  Thanks.